# Sending custom error from Node/Express to Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express

I am sending an HTTP request from angular to a node/express API. How do I get the actual error message I send from the node/express API

I am handling my exceptions well when they are thrown in the API but the moment I try to read the message in Angular I only get the name of the type of error I throw. For example, if I throw a 409 the error received by angular is just "Conflict" and does not contain the details I send. Please look at my code below.

I am sending my request as below

```
register(user: UserAccount) {
    return this.http
      .post(`${config.apiUrl}/users/register`, user)
      .pipe(
        map((res: HttpResponse<Response>) => {
          return res;
        }))
      .pipe(catchError(err => this.errorHandler.handleError(err)));
  }
```

My handle error is as below:

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    console.log(error);
    if (error) {
      let errMessage = '';
      try {
        errMessage = error.message;
      } catch (error) {
        errMessage = error.statusText;
      }
      return throwError(errMessage || error || 'Server error');
    }
    return throwError(error.error || error || 'Server error');
  }
```

This how I am throwing my error when I occurs in my Node/Express API

```
 registerUser (req, res) {
    debug(chalk.blue(`*** insert user`))
    userRepo
      .create(req.body)
      .then(user => {
        debug(chalk.green(`*** Insert User ok!`))
        res.status(200).json({
          status: true,
          error: null,
          user: user
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        debug(chalk.red(`*** insertUser error: ${util.inspect(err)}`))
        if (err['type'] && err['type'] === '409') {
          res.status(409).json({
            status: false,
            error: err['message'],
            user: null
          })
        } else {
          res.status(400).json({
            status: false,
            error: err,
            user: null
          })
        }
      })
  }
```

I want to be able to receive the json object with the information about the error but all I am getting when I access the error item is, for example, in the case of raising a 409, I only get 'Conflict'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that when you catch the error and the status is a 409, you return `err['message'] instead of 'err'.

So instead of:

```
res.status(409).json({
            status: false,
            error: err['message'],
            user: null
          })
```

You should return:

```
res.status(409).json({
                status: false,
                error: err,
                user: null
              })
```

This is actually what you do in the case of a 400 error!

Comment: Thank you for you response. Its not actually the solution but you answer led me to the right solution. I adjusted you answer to match the working solution

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what was the problem then? :)

Comment: the problem was I was returning the object:  res.status(409).json({ status: false, error: err, user: null}) instead of just doing res.status(409).json(err). Accept my edits to update the answer